# how to prevent Error messages on the site can be controlled by the user. (Spring web application)

Tags: spring, http, server

we have a spring web application and have a domain name such as:-`example.com`

But on the application the server status can be configured by the user if the site is down.

For example: If we hit the application as:-`example.com/server-status/this` is a test message.

This message gets published on the browser.This can help attackers to send malicious messages to the user.

I have tried various alternative but unable to stop it.Please help in this regard.Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve, but if I understood it clearly, you can use Spring Security to prevent not logged (or even without admin role) users to send requests to `example.com/server-status/this`.

For tutorials how to implement Spring Security look for example here:
http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-security-tutorials/

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response..I will try to explain in a better way  example.com/server-status/this.The problem i am facing is whatever data you give after server-status in the url will be displayed on the browser.Suppose i edit the url as example.com/server-status/Hello World send me a message on 1230 to access the sit.The below data will be displayed in the user.How to prevent such kind of url editing